# Create custom form and submit data to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I’m having troubles with submitting data from custom html form to the data extension.

The current setup is:

- microsite with 2 pages
- 2-field form on the first page (dropdown field, and text filed)
- AMPscript on the second page

The first problem is that dropdown field value is never making it’s way to DE.  Second text field is OK. But than the second problem arises in a couple of hours: the whole flow stops working, and I have this:
“500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.”

Form on first page:

```html
<form class="sms_form_1" method="post" action="https://cloud.marketing.subdomain/unsub-sms-2">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="column_1">
   <label class="description">Prefix</label>
   <select id="element_3" mame="prefix"> 
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose</option>
     <option value="43">+43</option>
     <option value="49">+49</option>
     <option value="385">+385</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="column_2">
   <label class="description">Phone</label>
   <input id="element_2" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{5,10}" placeholder="eg. 994023461" name="number">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="column_full">
   <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Unsubscribe">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Processing page:

```vb
%%[   
    set @pref = RequestParameter("prefix")
    set @num = RequestParameter("number")

    set @result = InsertData("DE_name", "Prefix", @pref, "Phone", @num)
]%%

%%=v(@result)=%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is, that you have a typo in your Prefix-select. Instead of `mame` you need to put `name`. Then the value should be passed correctly:

```html
<select id="element_3" name="prefix">
```

If the process works at first submission, I guess the rest of the problem lies within the data extension, so my guess is that there is some kind of primary key violation, etc.
If you reviewed the data extension and cannot find an issue I suggest you add the data extension configuration to your question and try debugging your code with an SSJS try/catch-block and supplying the given (more detailed) error message:

```html
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core","1"); 
    try {
</script>

%%[   
    set @pref = RequestParameter("prefix")
    set @num = RequestParameter("number")

    set @result = InsertData("DE_name", "Prefix", @pref, "Phone", @num)
]%%

%%=v(@result)=%%

<script runat="server">
    } catch (e) {
        Write("e: " + Stringify(e));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Markus!

Comment: @VitalyBelyakov You are welcome! If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted, so others can easily see this has been solved. If the second problem is still present, please add the error message and dat extension details to your question so further investigation is possible.